# Swift 3 String Contains Exact Sentence / Word

Tags: swift

I would like to know a simple algorithm to determine if a string contains exact sentence or word.

**I'm not looking for:**

`string.contains(anotherString)`

Here's why:

```
let string = "I know your name"
string.contains("you") // Will return true
```

In the example above, it returns true because if find `"you"` in the word `"your"`. I want a method  that will return false in that condition.

**For example:**

```
let string = "I am learning Swift"

// Let's say we make a method using extension called contains(exact:)
string.contains(exact: "learn") // return false
```

The method `contains(exact:)` will return false since `"learn"` is not equal with `"learning"`

**Another example:**

```
let string = "Healthy low carb diets"
string.contains(exact: "low carb diet") // return false
```

What's the algorithm to get that result in Swift 3? Or is there predefined method for this?

Comment: You could iterate through the words and compare them using `==`.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I thought that one too, but we can't determine if there is double space between words and it shouldn't match.

Comment: Then you should handle that before. I'm not sure the built-in trimming white-spaces function does it. If not, just check for `  ` (two subsequent spaces) and then delete one of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution is Regular Expression which is able to check for word boundaries.

This is a simple String extension, the pattern searches for the query string wrapped in word boundaries (`\b`)

```
extension String {
    func contains(word : String) -> Bool
    {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\b\(word)\\b")
            return regex.numberOfMatches(in: self, range: NSRange(word.startIndex..., in: word)) > 0
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Or – thanks to Sulthan – still simpler

```
extension String {
    func contains(word : String) -> Bool
    {
        return self.range(of: "\\b\(word)\\b", options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let string = "I know your name"
string.contains(word:"your") // true
string.contains(word:"you") // false
```

Comment: I completely forgot about regex. This works perfectly and also can match multiple words.

Comment: Does this find a word at the start (or end) of the string?

Comment: While this is correct, do you really need `NSRegularExpression`? Wouldn't `self.range(of: "\\b\(word)\\b", options: .regularExpression) != nil` do the same?

Comment: Also, you would probably have to escape the `word`, to be sure there are no dangeours characters.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it does

Comment: For anyone who uses this code, please make sure to check the word length first. Because if we specify `""` (empty string) as the parameter, it will return true, which is unexpected.

Comment: @vadian Not working in case of case-sensitive. I tested with word f##k, It didn't match with F##k.

Comment: @iDeveloper You mean *case-**in**sensitive*. Of course not, you have to add the `.caseInsensitive` option to `NSRegularExpression` and `range(of` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

A regexless solution would be something like:

```
yourString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted)
    .filter { $0 != "" } // this is here os that it always evaluates to false if wordToFind is "". Feel free to remove this line if you don't need it.
    .contains(wordToFind)
```

This will treat every non-alphanumeric character as a word boundary.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't cover the multi-word query.

Comment: @vadian No this doesn't. I missed that requirement. Checking multiple words regexlessly would need some array manipulation, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

```
func containsExact(_ findString: String, _ inString: String) -> Bool {
    let expression = "\\b\(findString)\\b"
    return inString.range(of: expression, options: .regularExpression) != nil
}
```