# How to get a String Contains number of Exact Sentence / Word in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I looking for in my string exact number of word/sentence for example:
What i am tried:

```
let str = "Art of swift, now art of swift5 but this is true art of swift from 2014 now what do you think about art of swift?"
var search = "art of swift"

str.contains(word:search)
var count = str.lowercased().components(separatedBy: search.lowercased()).count
print(count - 1)
```

output:

```
  4
```

I am looking for it should be `3` because of `art of swift5` not looking for search.

In the example above, it returns 4 because of found "art of swift" in the word "art of swift5". I want a method that will return 3 in that condition.

**But method have more few case:**

**Allow**
 case-insensitive for user can be upper case or lower it doesn't matter for search result counter. example user put `Art of swift` in the text string has `art of swift`

```
 Art of swift // it will return true as found 1
```

any special character allow for example `? , . etc`

```
art of swift? // it will return true as found 1
```

even special character with character allow for example `

```
art of swift's // it will return true as found 1
```

**Don't allow:**
 don't allowing different language character for example

```
art of swiftবাং // it will return false as not found 0
```

even it not allowing same language character

```
art of swiftly // it will return false as not found 0
```

Why need it?

i am trying to implement search result items show it base on best match priority.

Comment: You need to be precise with your search criteria. You've made it case-insensitive, which doesn't match your "exact" requirement. And it's not clear what symbols you consider boundaries. Would "art of swift." (with a trailing period) be a match? how about "art of swift's"? How about "D'art of swift?" (including or not including the trailing question mark). When you express your requirement explicitly, the code will generally fall out naturally. "Word" is a very flexible term. Another example that matters: "art      of     swift"   Does that count, with lots of spaces between the words?

Comment: (StackOverflow comments strip away all the extra spaces, but consider the case of multiple spaces, or newlines, between the words. Do they still count?)

Comment: good point! i consider all symbol but  i can not consider `swift5`

Comment: @RobNapier if multiple space between the search word then i will trim to one space but if the string  multiple spaces, or newlines, between the words then result  will be not found.

Comment: I think Rob's point is that you need to explicitly define all of your requirements first. Here you have posted a string and a search term but have not defined all of the expectations of that search. Without specific requirements, we will not be able to give you an accurate answer. Right now you suggest that `swift5` is invalid. What else is invalid that you haven't told us yet? Write everything out and this will become much easier.

Comment: Sounds like you have quite a few rules (as I suspected). You haven't defined what "all symbol" is for example. Does it include apostrophe? How about if it were `swift٥` (using a 5 like one would write in Arabic). Is it just "0 through 9" or is it "numerals?" You should start by writing test cases that capture as many of these rules as you can think of. Then explore implementations (and we can help with that).

Comment: If you have preconditions like "I know this is exclusively ASCII text," then that's also useful information. All these rules and preconditions will radically change what kind of solution works. Some are very complicated, while others may be very simple. You don't want to have to do the most complicated ones if you actually have a very simple problem. We just don't know yet whether this is a simple or complex problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 String Contains Exact Sentence / Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437105/swift-3-string-contains-exact-sentence-word)

Comment: @KirilS. it's only check word exist or not. but i am looking number of mach Word/Sentence  in the String. because of it's working for search engine return maximum mach

Comment: did you even look at the solution? `return regex.numberOfMatches` etc. All you need is to change from returning boolean to number. So yes, it's the same question

Comment: @KirilS. i have some of special `? . 0-9` here is allow for return true as number counter fund

Comment: You should leave a comment what's wrong with this post. i am open to update and discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    func nazmulCount(of needle: String) -> Int {
        let pattern = "\\b" + NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: needle) + "\\b"
        let rex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [.caseInsensitive])
        return rex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(startIndex..., in: self)).count
    }
}

"Art of swift, now art of swift5 but this is true art of swift from 2014 now what do you think about art of swift?".nazmulCount(of: "art of swift")
// 3

"Art of swift".nazmulCount(of: "art of swift")
// 1

"art of swift?".nazmulCount(of: "art of swift")
// 1

"art of swift's".nazmulCount(of: "art of swift")
// 1

"art of swiftবাং".nazmulCount(of: "art of swift")
// 0

"art of swiftly".nazmulCount(of: "art of swift")
// 0
```